# In the code shown below, I'm not able to print the array in reverse order

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, reverse

In the code shown below, I'm not being able to print the array in reverse order. The rest of the code is working fine except for the reverse part. How can I solve this issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int i;
    printf("Enter the values into the array and see them in normal and reverse order\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Enter the number of elements into the array\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("Input %d elmements into the array:\n", i);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
    {
        printf("elemenet - %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\nThe values stored into the array are:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
    {
        printf("%3d",arr[i] );
    }
    printf("\nThe values stored into the array in reverse order are:\n");
    for (i = 0; i > 10; i --) \*something wrong here*\
    {
        printf("%5d",arr[i] );
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

In particular the part from the code where the reverse of array is applied is shown below:

```
printf("\nThe values stored into the array in reverse order are:\n");
    for (i = 0; i > 10; i --) \*something wrong here*\
    {
        printf("%5d",arr[i] );
    }
```

Im not able to figure out how to reverse it. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Input %d elmements into the array:\n", i);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i ++)`  this is making the assumption that the user entered 10 for the number of elements in the array.  This is a bad assumption and will cause problems

Comment: regarding; `
    int i;
    ....
    scanf("%d", &i);`  this sets variable `i` to the number of elements to be input by the user.  However, this: `for (i = 0; i < 10; i ++)` destroys that number.  Suggest using a different variable for the number of elements with a name like: `maxElements`.

Comment: regarding: `int arr[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};`  this declares a fixed size array of 10 rather than using the count entered by the user.  Suggest 1) move this statement to after the user enters the number of elements AND modify the statement to:  `int arr[ i ];`  (which uses the `Variable Length Array` feature of C.)

Answer (score 4):

Read your code:

```
for (i = 0; i > 10; i --)
```

it says: run from i=0 as long as i>10. this is of course not what you meant.

try changing it to

```
for (i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print in the reverse order, you need to start `i` at the largest index and the loop condition should ensure that `i` is positive:

```
for (i=9; i>=0; i--)
{
    printf("%5d",arr[i] );
}
```